# Syntax to select into two variables in one select statement (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Isn't it possible to select into two variables in a single select statement?  Please help me get this simple syntax.  **id** and **date_start** both are columns in the table **data_set**.  The WHERE clause restricts the results to one row.  Naturally, when I do this as two selects, one for each variable, it works.

```
select id into @id_data_set, date_start into @start_date from data_set
where name_table = 'debug_data_1';

ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: date_start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just correct your sql syntax : at first list all fields and after that, in the `INTO` clause, list all variables. For more information look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html). Your query :

```
SELECT id
     , date_start 
INTO @id_data_set
   , @start_date
FROM data_set
WHERE name_table = 'debug_data_1';
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot.  I knew this was a boneheaded question, but I was stuck.  I read and reread the Select page a dozen times, too, overlooking the obvious.  Sometimes, you just need to be told.  Thanks.